# Canon DR-2050C Scanner with Mac OSX

Tags: macos, scanner

Is there any way to use a Canon DR-2050C scanner on OSX? I bought the scanner, but it doesn't come with any OSX drivers. Neither can one be found on the Canon website.

(A definite negative would help also so I can get rid of this thing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Canon don't support OSX for this machine, officially it's a definite negative ~ enought to take it back. If the retailer complains, suggest he/she contact Canon.
Having said that, it might work with software from a similar scanner, or even the Mac version of Canoscan. If you have the time, go fishing on the Canon site.
Regards
Paul

Answer (score 0):

If you really have your heart set on this scanner you can check out [VueScan](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/4763/vuescan) though that adds another $40 to your cost.

Comment: Ach! And I was ready to sell it too. So...do you know that this works for sure or just theoretically? I don't mind spending the extra dough since I got the scanner at a discount anyway. But I don't want to waste any more money on it if I'm not sure it will work.

Comment: I believe it has a free trial that watermarks the images. I looked for a list of supported scanners but didn't see one.

Comment: Here's the list of supported scanners from their website. The DR2050C fom Canon is not on there, unfortunately.http://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/vuescan.htm#supported